# Problems with saving value of superglobal in PHP

Tags: php

This code doesn't work:

```
$john = array("goodie");

function test(){
    global $john;
    for($i=0; $i<100; $i++)
    {
         array_push($john, "pro");
    }
    print_r($john);
}

test(); // outputs correct array: array("goodie","pro","pro"....)

/* then when again function is called */

test(); // output is NULL
        // with 100 errors in loop:
        // expects parameter 1 to be an array, NULL given...
```

I have problems to fix this in my code, and I don't understand problem. Why instead adding new 100 items in array, global variable is unset.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://3v4l.org/dRKgO

Comment: ^ Worked fine for me too running locally on xampp

Comment: Which `PHP` version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason why global variables are generally evil.  Because its global, it's probably getting modified somewhere, possibly in some obscure fashion that's hard to detect.  Instead of making it global, why not pass it in as a parameter and return it back out?

```
function test(array $param){
    for($i=0; $i<100; $i++)
    {
         array_push($param, "pro");
    }
    return $param;
}

$john = array(); 

$john = test($john);

// ...

$john = test($john);
```

Comment: I give sample of code, simplified, sometimes that function is called from other function, or with different types of arguments, I dont like to use global variables, but this is easiest way for some simple but long code, where is no need for some security or something special.

Comment: @Ivan Your simplified version does not reflect the actual problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use your globals in that way. A function should be a closed part of your code. So its much better to make an input parameter and work with the variable like that.

```
function test(array $input) {
    for($i=0; $i<100; $i++) {
         array_push($input, "pro");
    }
    return $input;
}
```